# How to have a record show up in the table 1 for each year, and then have the calculated values be automatically associated in the second table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I am calculate/grab a bunch of data using GROUPING_ID and am trying to

1) have a record in the **CALCULATION** table created for each distinct YEAR and

2) have the calculated VALUE correlated to that year be inserted as being related in the **CALCULATION_REL** relationship table and

3) insert the calculated value into the VALUE table (this part is fairly straightforward)

So essentially below is my cursor that I am using to grab data:

```
CURSOR a1 is
select
  to_char(hr, 'yyyy') yyyy,
  sum(value_nb) total,
  max(value_nb) maxval,
  color
  form_field form_field,
  grouping_id(to_char(hr, 'yyyy'), form_field, color) AS group_level_nb
from
  value v
  left outer join submission_value_rel sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
  left outer join submission s on sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
group by cube (to_char(hr, 'yyyy'), form_field_tx, color);
```

I want something like this:

**Calculation (Table)**

```
Calculation_ID   Year
     1           2016
     2           2017
     3           2018
```

**Value (Table)**

```
Value_ID      Value       Date       Color      Shape    GROUPING_ID
   1           7          2016       Blue        NULL        2 
   2           3          2016       Red         NULL        2
   3           99         2016       Green      Circle       3
   4           1          2017       Blue       Square       3
   5           2          2017       Purple     Square       3
   6           5          2018       Green      Circle       3
   7           4          2018       White      Square       3
```

**Calculation_Rel (Table)**

```
 Calculation_ID    Value_Id
     1                1
     1                2
     1                3
     2                4
     2                5
     3                6
     3                7
```

The best that I can think of is creating two separate cursors, opening one for the insert into the **CALCULATION** table and then closing it. Opening the second cursor for the insert into the **VALUE** and **Calculation_Rel** and then somehow tying it back together. Or looping through just one cursor and creating a calculation_id for each calculation / value relationship (not optimal but I guess this is my last resort of I can't figure out a way to do what I showed above. Below is my attempt using the 'looping through approach' that I described in my previous sentence:

```
BEGIN 
  Open a1;
  LOOP
  FETCH a1 into a_var;
  EXIT WHEN a1%NOTFOUND;
      IF grouping_id = 2
      THEN
      insert into calculation(calculation_id, year)
                      values (null, a_var.yyyy)
            returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
      -- Calculation_id is auto-generated via a trigger / sequence
      insert into value(value_id, value, date, color)
                 values(null, a_var.sum, a_var.color)
            returning value_id into v_value_id;
      -- Value_id is auto-generated via a trigger / sequence
      insert into calculation_Rel(Calculation_id, Value_Id)
                          values (v_calculation_id, v_value_id);
      ELSIF grouping_id = 3
      THEN
      insert into calculation(calculation_id, year)
                      values (null, a_var.yyyy)
            returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
      -- Calculation_id is auto-generated via a trigger / sequence
      insert into value(value_id, value, date, color)
                 values(null, a_var.max, a_var.color)
            returning value_id into v_value_id;
      -- Value_id is auto-generated via a trigger / sequence
      insert into calculation_Rel(Calculation_id, Value_Id)
                          values (v_calculation_id, v_value_id); 
      END IF;
   commit;
   END LOOP;
   Close C1;
   END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid cursors and try to insert/create rows using your Source SQL, SQL queries below should give you base idea on how to achieve this without cursors.

Ex (Edited after OP updated question to handle based on group_level_nb):
Assuming (your original SQL is incomplete and not clear which field is stored in which for value table from cursor variable) - YYYY is being stored in the date field of value table.

```
--create value table rows
INSERT INTO Value (Value, Date, Color)
SELECT 
case 
 when group_level_nb = 2 then total
 when group_level_nb = 3 then maxval
end, yyyy, color from
(
    select
      sum(value_nb) total,
      to_char(hr, 'yyyy') yyyy,
      sum(value_nb) total,
      max(value_nb) maxval,
      color
      form_field form_field,
      grouping_id(to_char(hr, 'yyyy'), form_field, color) AS group_level_nb
    from
      value v
      left outer join submission_value_rel sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
      left outer join submission s on sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
    group by cube (to_char(hr, 'yyyy'), form_field_tx, color)
) src
WHERE group_level_nb IN (2,3);

--create calculation table rows
INSERT INTO Calculation (year)
SELECT DISTINCT Date From Value;

--create rel table
INSERT INTO Calculation_Rel (Calculation_id, Value_Id)
SELECT B.Calculation_id, A.Value_Id
FROM Value A
INNER JOIN Calculation B ON A.Date = B.Year;
```

Comment: sorry, I meant 'sum' and instead I put 'value'. I edited my code :)  thanks for your response!

Comment: @JohnWick, By sum you meant to say Total field? Also what about Date column?

Comment: Also your approach is not exactly what I am looking for, I need a way to return the calculation_value_id generated by the sequence into the v_calculation_id variable (to re-use)?

Comment: @JohnWick, the above SQL will exactly do what you are trying to do in your SQL example above and 3 steps defined in the Question, can you add more and explain how you want to use v_calculation_id again other than trying to insert into calculation_rel table?

Comment: what I had above is a watered down version but there will be multiple IF statements where there is another column called GROUPING_ID where certain columns (whether it be Total, MAXVAL, MIN, etc.) will be grabbed based off this 'GROUPING_ID' I've edited my original question to reflect that (my apologies).

Comment: @JohnWick, you can still achieve that using SQL approach i mentioned. Check updated SQL. I still don't see use of v_calculation_id other than being used in creating relation rows.